# Fluent Nhibernate Many to Many Mapping Way

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have two classes Order and Items

I want a method like this

```
class Order
{
    public virtual IList<Item> GetItems(Order order)
    {
         //get items for that order.
    }
}
class Item
{
    public virtual IList<Order> GetOrders(Item item)
    {
         //get all the orders in which that items is present.
    }
}
```

Is it write to create a method like this or instead should I create a property

```
     public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

And how should I do the mapping for this is nhibernate??

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Apparently you have a many-to-many relationship: An order can have many items and an item can belong to many orders. In a relational database you need to express this with a separate table which I presume you have - let's assume this table is called `OrdersItems`.

Following the Store/Product example from the [Fluent NHibernate documentation](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started#your-first-project) you would create an `Items` property in an `Order` and an `Orders` property in `Item`:

```
class Order
{
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; protected set; }
}

class Item
{
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; protected set; }
}
```

And the mappings:

```
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Items)
           .Cascade.All()
           .Table("OrdersItems");
    }
}

public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Orders)
           .Cascade.All()
           .Inverse()
           .Table("OrdersItems");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was missing the ".Inverse()", for future reference, if one does not use it, the table "OrdersItems" makes a double registry.

Answer (score 0):

What would the OrdersItems look like as a class? How would this class map with table in DB if I want to use this class i order to check if there is a certain record? Would apreciate the help

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34665948)